# Large HTML render/output from a WordPress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making custom WP plugin which will have shortcode. This shortcode will have attribute of category slug and according to category slug it will fetch post and show first 5 of them with their featured images into a carousel or custom slider. The output will have a large HTML fragment.

Here the very basic code

```
function posts_from_category( $atts ) {
   ob_start();
    global $posts;
    $args = array('category_name' => $atts['category_slug'] );
    $posts = get_posts( $args );
   //Here either I want to include a php file as template and pass the $posts some how which I am not able to do or make string concatenated HTML fragment or heredoc.
   return ob_get_clean();
}


add_shortcode("posts_from_category", 'posts_from_category');
```

I want to use it as

```
[posts_from_category category_slug="services"]
```

Please help me how it can be done at best as I am new to php and WP.

Comment: get_template_part(PATH_OF_THE_FILE) (eg: get_template_file('myslide','template'); and your should have template file with name myslide-template.php

Comment: How do I pass the $posts to this file ? Its same as require

Comment: you just use : include(locate_template('your-template-name.php')); all of variables from of your function is available inside your template. For more informations : http://keithdevon.com/passing-variables-to-get_template_part-in-wordpress/

Comment: nops man it not working

Comment: Update your code to see

Comment: Yes it is checked as you have stated.